# Return null from fun in kotlin

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, kotlin

I've written a function to perform a database query. I want it to return `null` if it cannot fetch any result.

```
fun getServiceCharge(model: String): ServiceChargeMasterList {
    val unique = VideoconApplication.daoSession.serviceChargeMasterListDao.queryBuilder().where(ServiceChargeMasterListDao.Properties.ModelCategory.eq(model)).unique()
    if (unique != null)
        return unique
    else
        return null!!
}
```

It gives me **`kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException`**.

Can anyone tell me how can I solve this?

Answer (score 13):

Just specify your return type as `ServiceChargeMasterList?` and return `null`. The `!!` operator is very ugly to use.

You don't even have to use that `if` statement if your `unique()` method return and optional (or Java object). In that case, you method could look like this:

```
fun getServiceCharge(model: String): ServiceChargeMasterList? {
    return VideoconApplication.daoSession.serviceChargeMasterListDao.queryBuilder().where(ServiceChargeMasterListDao.Properties.ModelCategory.eq(model)).unique()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this

```
fun getServiceCharge(model: String): ServiceChargeMasterList? = 
    VideoconApplication.
    daoSession.
    serviceChargeMasterListDao.
    queryBuilder().
    where(ServiceChargeMasterListDao.Properties.ModelCategory.eq(model)).
    unique()
```

**Explanation**

In Kotlin, there are *optional types*. If you return ServiceChargeMasterList, you say to the compiler that you will never return null. If you want to return null, you have to add ? sign at the end of the type which indicates that you can return an instance of ServiceChargeMasterList or null.

The operator !! can be explained in Java as

```
//Kotlin
variable!!


//Java
if (variable == null)
    throw new kotlin.NullPointerException();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method’s return type does not allow `null` to be returned. You need to change it to it’s nullable version`ServiceChargeMasterList?` (nullability denoted by the question mark).

The not-null assertion operator `!!` should only be used in very rare cases because it tries to transform nullable types into non-nullable types and **might throw** a `NullPointerException` when invoked on `null`.
Your code `null!!` is the perfect demonstration for this.

Instead of applying safe operators like in `nullableVar?.foo()`, this operator is used like this: `nullableVar!!.foo()`.

In your case though, the `!!` operator is the wrong choice. If your method is really supposed to return `null`, change the return type.

Answer (score 1):

```
open fun getProfile() : ProfileModel? {
    if (MyApplication.sharedPreference.getString("profile","")!=null){
        var profileModel : ProfileModel = Profile()
        return profileModel
    }
    return null 
}
```

**add ? after your return type** then **return null** it works